# Linux Centos6 VM How to format the namenode?

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos

I'm trying to start hadoop on my Centos6 VM linux. 
these steps have been followed

- yum install hadoop* mahout* oozie* hbase* hive* hue* pig*
  zookeeper* done
- yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64  done
- yum install sudo done
- yum install nano done
- sudo /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode init   fail -->sudo:
  update-rc.d: command not found

I checked etc/init.d and there is nothing like hadoop-hdfs-namenode. Instead of this command i found this hadoop namenode -format and executed. And it worked then next step

- for i in hadoop-hdfs-namenode hadoop-hdfs-datanode ;  do sudo service
  $i start ; done

I executed this command but got unrecognized service error.

Centos version 6.2-x64

Answer (score 0):

When you first install Hadoop, you must configure it following this https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html

Use this command to format a new distributed filesystem and namenode

```
$ $HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format <cluster_name>
```